# possible to use tuple, deconstruct with request.user, django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, destructuring

Normally, I know tuple can be used as

`(email, username) = ('hello', 'user')`

that `email` will be equal to `hello`

But I am wondering if I can do something like

`(email, username) = request.user` so I do  not have to keep on typing `request.user` and instead just use `email` and `username` like how `javascript` works.

if I did the above, I would get an error saying `TypeError: object is not iterable`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and advices.

Answer (score 1):

The *destructuring* mechanism in python works with a **"positional"** manner (as you have used it in `(email, username) = ('hello', 'user')`.

It does not work in a **"named"** manner, as you have tried in `(email, username) = request.user`, as javascript do.